# How to find out what the order of the base point of the elliptic curve is?

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation

I wanted to use https://github.com/AntonKueltz/fastecdsa library and the function parameters for creating curve are:

```
p,  # (long): The value of p in the curve equation.
a,  # (long): The value of a in the curve equation.
b,  # (long): The value of b in the curve equation.
q,  # (long): The order of the base point of the curve.
gx,  # (long): The x coordinate of the base point of the curve.
gy,  # (long): The y coordinate of the base point of the curve.
```

The curve I need is this one: https://docs.starkware.co/starkex-docs-v2-deprecated/crypto/stark-curve
It gives info about $p, a, b, gx, gy$. But not the $q$

How to infer the $q$ parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretical answer here

- [How to determine the order of an elliptic curve group from its parameters?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/27904/18298)

  - [Schoof's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoof%27s_algorithm), René Schoof, 1985 with complexity $\mathcal{O}(\log^8 q)$
  - [Schoof–Elkies–Atkin algorithm (SEA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoof%E2%80%93Elkies%E2%80%93Atkin_algorithm) with complexity $\mathcal{O}(\log^6 q)$

Practically, one can use [SageMath](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNUF1Lw0AQfL9fcfiU2FD283bvwSep_RFiJa1RAqUNoRX8924UixwcM7c3szvb54eMaR83o6BWKsrq1SoTuxQqwuxMVhXIXbAalsq1simCOkE1qSIhZDDHIlBK0TSFIe1IMa8y2j3tsFJeYUqbKGyOx3G6jIfH6_w5NNunZmq7_Azdcvpu_9KmaR5Pl2ZzA-t-PxzH_vT6MZ-vU9O2KR36-W3xWi9gPPXH8fLV_Anu_j3mh7tuoW167w-X89z8krRd1I2bGFeJMOYAZqWImhSpsQMTJgLnYGRewJSZIq0jKrJTADDy4h6hgTpUivBWCSw-uDNETU1VYzMUOlYGQSEQWNotjR1ZohR2SKRK6gUF7BZkO5yGuY-x83l-G-YlTN6uf3Cs4RtWHG6l&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) to find it;

```
a = 1
b = 3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406665
p = 2^251 + 17*2^192 +1

E = EllipticCurve(GF(p), [0,0,0,a,b])
print(E)
print(E.abelian_group())

card = E.cardinality()
print("cardinality =",card)
factor(card)

G = E(874739451078007766457464989774322083649278607533249481151382481072868806602,152666792071518830868575557812948353041420400780739481342941381225525861407)
print("Generator order q=", G.order())
```

This outputs

```
    Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + x + 3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406665 over Finite Field of size 3618502788666131213697322783095070105623107215331596699973092056135872020481
Additive abelian group isomorphic to Z/3618502788666131213697322783095070105526743751716087489154079457884512865583 embedded in Abelian group of points on Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + x + 3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406665 over Finite Field of size 3618502788666131213697322783095070105623107215331596699973092056135872020481
cardinality = 3618502788666131213697322783095070105526743751716087489154079457884512865583
Generator order q= 3618502788666131213697322783095070105526743751716087489154079457884512865583
```

Since the order of the curve is prime we have a **prime curve**, every element, except the identity, is a generator, therefore the order of the basepoint is equal to the order of the curve group.

Also, the cofactor  $h$ is 1 since the curve order is prime. Cofactor is defined as the number of the $k$ rational points of the curve $h = \#E(k)/n $ divided by the order of the chosen base element $n$

I couldn't find any information about the magic number ([nothing-up-in-my-sleeve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing-up-my-sleeve_number)). The reason for the choice of $G$ is not clear. Although it is [psychological](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/16366/18298), one should provide it.

---

[SageMath uses sea.gp](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/thematic_tutorials/explicit_methods_in_number_theory/elliptic_curves.html) which is a fast implementation of the SEA algorithm. This library is implemented in [pari/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/). A good slide about sea.gp is [The SEA algorithm in PARI/GP](https://lfant.math.u-bordeaux.fr/seminar/slides/2015-11-24T11:00--Julien_Keuffer.pdf).