# How to decompose a public key into subgroups EC?

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, keys, key-generation, elliptic-curve-generation

Is it possible to decompose the public key into its own subgroups?
Suppose we know the order `P` with which the public key was generated `(Qx, Qy)`

How can the public key `(Qx, Qy)` be decomposed into subgroups of small orders?

I saw in [SageMath](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/arithmetic_curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_finite_field.html) it is possible to work with `Elliptic Curves`

```
M = EllipticCurve (GF (p), [0.7])
```

I am just getting familiar with `SageMath` and am having a hard time working on creating a generator on order.
Are there examples of these works?

Comment: A public key is a GROUP ELEMENT, which is a point with coordinates taken from a finite field in elliptical curves, AND NOT a group itself. I don't know what you mean by  "decompose public key into its own subgroups". The EC group used is (generally) a large prime order (sub)group in the curve. Which means it has no non-trivial subgroup and every valid public key point generates the entire (sub)group.

Comment: Do you mean determine which subgroups it belongs? Well, factor the order of the group and use the Lagrange theorem of each of the factors; if $5$ is a factor and $[5]P = \mathcal{O}$ then the order of $P$ is 5...

Comment: @kelalaka
 Yes, it is kelalaka that I thank for the quick reply. How do I do this in SageMath? I add `E = EllipticCurve(GF(p), [0,7])
Grp = E.abelian_group()
g = Grp.gens()[0]
numElements = g.order()`  ,but unfortunately I get an error

Comment: [cardinality and factor?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/95667/18298)

Comment: Note, for direct SageMath errors, there is https://ask.sagemath.org/